# How do I use Linq in MonoDevelop 2.0 on OS X?

Tags: linq, mono, monodevelop

I installed MonoDevelop 2.0 on my Mac.

I created a new Console Application.

"Hello World" program runs fine.

But I can't use Linq.

`using System.` doesn't show `Linq` option.

What should I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may need to right-click on your project in the solution view, do `Options`, `Build`, `General`, and set your Target Runtime to `Mono / .Net 3.5` or bigger.

Then you can right-click references, do Edit References, and add a reference to System.Core to your project.

Comment: also.. not only the target but YOUR project needs to be 3.5 as well (I had issues where my project was 2.0 and pointing to a mono/net 3.5 proj and it freaked)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew what how to target the runtime but didn't know that I needed to change the core lib.

Answer (score 6):

I'm running Monodevelop 2.0 and Mono 2.0 on Ubuntu 9.04 and lambda's and Linq work fine.

Contrary to what Thomas Levesque says, `System.Core` does exist in Mono. Extension methods, lambda's et al are all supported.

You need to use `using System.Linq`.

```
public static void Example1()    
{

    List<string> people = new List<string>() 
    { 
        "Granville", "John", "Rachel", "Betty", 
        "Chandler", "Ross", "Monica" 
    };

    IEnumerable<string> query = from p in people where p.Length > 5 
    orderby p select p;

    foreach (string person in query) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I added 'using System.Linq' and got the following error when I compiled.

[Task:File=/Users/ssk/Projects/Test Linq 4/Test Linq 4/Main.cs, Line=17, Column=50, Type=Error, Priority=Normal, Description=An implementation of `Where' query expression pattern could not be found. Are you missing `System.Linq' using directive or `System.Core.dll' assembly reference?(CS1935)]

Comment: What happens when you try to run the example code? Which type are you trying to call Where on?

Answer (score 1):

Is your Console Application referencing the `System.Core.dll`? You need to reference it in order to use `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 1):

The Latest version of Mono Develop does support linq.  On the project you must select 3.5 under Build/General/RuntimeVersion.  After that you can add the System.Core reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project references on System.**Xml.Linq** library too

Answer (score -2):

Not sure LINQ is fully implemented within the current release http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap